# Upload Image in MeanJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, meanjs, angular-fullstack

I can't upload image on my meanjs app, I don't know why but I can't nake the post to express.

I followed this example:
[Adding a picture to the MEAN.JS sample with Angular-file-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029413/adding-a-picture-to-the-mean-js-sample-with-angular-file-upload/28148042#28148042)

But my service in angular use $resource to make a post, ex:

```
'use strict'; 
angular.module('eventos').factory('Eventos', ['$resource',
function($resource){
        return $resource('events/eventId', {eventId:'@_id'
},{
   update:{
          method:'PUT'
          }
    });
  }
]);
```

There are other approach?

I tried to find examples or tutorials but there isn't, could you help?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Hard time... I solved my uploading image problem following this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019134/how-to-upload-an-image-file-to-mongoose-database-using-mean-js/28343983#28343983).

Answer (score 0):

I used the Angular solution found here: https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

Then I combined this with Multer (Express Middleware), as described in this Stackoverflow question here:

[Use Multer in Express Route? (Using MEANJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785896/user-multer-in-express-route-using-meanjs)

This works pretty well for me.